# Wrapping the jquery-ui slider results in "undefined is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-ui, angularjs-directive

The following is the beginning of a wrapper for the jquery-ui slider.

```
app.directive('sliderWidget', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        scope: {
            min: "@min",
            max: "@max",
            step: "@step"
        },
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
            elem.slider({
                min: scope.min,
                max: scope.max,
                step: scope.step,
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    //ngModel.$setViewValue(ui.value);
                }
            });
            //ngModel.$render = function () {
            //  elem.slider('value', ngModel.$viewValue);
            //  $timeout(function () { scope.$apply() });
            //};
        }
    };
}]);

<div slider-widget min=0 max=99 step=1 ng-model="someValue"></div>
```

However, even as it is, with all the main parts commented out, when a slide event occurs I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function --> jquery-ui.js:11881
```

I'm using:

jQuery v2.1.1

jQuery UI - v1.10.4

AngularJS v1.2.16

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so when accessing one-way bound scope variables in a directive with an isolate scope, the values are represented as strings, even if they're defined with numerical constants in the attributes. I simply had to use parseFloat() to retrieve the numerical value.